# Flutter: How to change image position and add background text in Container?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am reproducing the design from the following image:

[reference design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHLIb.png)

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PlanetBox extends StatelessWidget {
  const PlanetBox({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        width: 200,
        height: 300,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
        ),
        child: Column(children: [
          Image.asset('assets/images/planets/1_sun.png',
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          const Text(
            "Sun",
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 5),
          const Text(
            "The Sun is the star at the center of the Solar System. It is a nearly perfect ball of hot plasma, heated to incandescence by nuclear fusion reactions in its core.",
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
          )
        ]));
  }
}
```

currently, my planet image is inside the box decoration

[current design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVuu3.png)

How can I change the position of the planet image (assets/images/planets/1_sun.png) and also add a background text (light grey 3 on the right side in reference design) in a container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add some background text by using a Stack Widget to place the children of the Container on top of each other like the following:

```dart
class PlanetBox extends StatelessWidget {
  const PlanetBox({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      width: 200,
      height: 300,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
      ),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            bottom: 40,
            right: 20,
            child: Text(
              "3",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 90, color: Colors.grey.withAlpha(100)),
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              Image.asset('assets/images/planets/1_sun.png', alignment: Alignment.topCenter),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              const Text(
                "Sun",
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 5),
              const Text(
                "The Sun is the star at the center of the Solar System. It is a nearly perfect ball of hot plasma, heated to incandescence by nuclear fusion reactions in its core.",
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this example the "3" is rendered similar to your reference picture.

And of course you could also add another `Positioned` widget for your image to position it with a distance to a corner.

Answer (score 0):

Your major concern is for you to position your planet image?
So, you can do that simply by wrapping your card widget in **Stack widget** and then add the image with a **Positioned widget** to which you can give it a negative property and you will be good to go.

```
Stack(    
children: [
... (Your card widget with the plane info)
Positioned(
  top: -40,
  right: 25.0,
  child: Image.network(
  'https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.iKEdZsVGxxPHhKA9pJ1gHgHaHZ?pid=ImgDet&rs=1',
  height: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height * 0.25,
  alignment: Alignment.topCenter)),
  ]),
```

Using Niko's code from above, I made a few changes and implemented the pageview builder. You can check the whole code [here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=999e91ff1fdef6a1a7351cae2d7d82fd)